# How can I add ZXingWidget as a dependency of my Xcode project

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, zxing, objective-c-2.0

1.I have successfully run the ScanTest example project in my xcode4.2.1

2.And then I try to include the ZXingWidget to my project with the ZXing README. I found that the ZXingWidget can not expand. see the pictures. I am going Mad with that.

Please help, thank you very much!!!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart the Xcode that problem should be fixed.